# print readable variables with golang

Tags: go

How to print a map, struct or whatever in a readable way?

With PHP you can to this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($var);
echo '</pre>';
```

or

```
header('content-type: text/plain');
print_r($var);
```

Comment: If you are generating HTML, do not do this with explicit Fprintf() statements unless you really know what you're doing.  Prefer `html/template`, which does proper escaping.  The code that you've written above is susceptible to a trivial injection attack.  Don't do that.  :P

Answer (score 20):

Use the Go [`fmt`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    variable := "var"
    fmt.Println(variable)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", variable)
    header := map[string]string{"content-type": "text/plain"}
    fmt.Println(header)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", header)
}
```

Output:

```
var
"var"
map[content-type:text/plain]
map[string]string{"content-type":"text/plain"}
```

> [Package fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> ```
> import "fmt"
> ```
>
> Overview
>
> Package fmt implements formatted I/O with functions analogous to C's
>   printf and scanf. The format 'verbs' are derived from C's but are
>   simpler.

Comment: It would be better if your example code also showed `%+v` and `%v`.

Answer (score 18):

I think in many cases, using "%v" is concise enough:

```
fmt.Printf("%v", myVar)
```

From the fmt package's documentation page:

> **%v**    the value in a default format.
>         when printing structs, the plus flag (**%+v**) adds field names
>
> **%#v**   a Go-syntax representation of the value

Here is an example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // Define a struct, slice and map
    type Employee struct {
        id   int
        name string
        age  int
    }
    var eSlice []Employee
    var eMap map[int]Employee

    e1 := Employee{1, "Alex", 20}
    e2 := Employee{2, "Jack", 30}
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", e1)
    // output: {1 Alex 20}
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", e1)
    // output: {id:1 name:Alex age:20}
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", e1)
    // output: main.Employee{id:1, name:"Alex", age:20}

    eSlice = append(eSlice, e1, e2)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", eSlice)
    // output: [{1 Alex 20} {2 Jack 30}]
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", eSlice)
    // output: []main.Employee{main.Employee{id:1, name:"Alex", age:20}, main.Employee{id:2, name:"Jack", age:30}}

    eMap = make(map[int]Employee)
    eMap[1] = e1
    eMap[2] = e2
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", eMap)
    // output: map[1:{1 Alex 20} 2:{2 Jack 30}]
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", eMap)
    // output: map[int]main.Employee{1:main.Employee{id:1, name:"Alex", age:20}, 2:main.Employee{id:2, name:"Jack", age:30}}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `fmt.Println()` to print. You will need to import the "fmt" package (see the example below). Many data types can be printed out of the box. If you want to get a human-readable print for custom types, you'll need to define a `String() string` method for that type.

To try the following example, click here: http://play.golang.org/p/M6_KnRJ3Da

```
package main

import "fmt"

// No `String()` method
type UnstringablePerson struct {
    Age int
    Name string
}

// Has a `String()` method
type StringablePerson struct {
    Age int
    Name string
}

// Let's define a String() method for StringablePerson, so any instances
// of StringablePerson can be printed how we like
func (p *StringablePerson) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s, age %d", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func main() {
    // Bobby's type is UnstringablePerson; there is no String() method
    // defined for this type, so his printout will not be very friendly
    bobby := &UnstringablePerson{
        Age: 10,
        Name: "Bobby",
    }

    // Ralph's type is StringablePerson; there *is* a String() method
    // defined for this type, so his printout *will* be very friendly
    ralph := &StringablePerson{
        Age: 12,
        Name: "Ralph",
    }
    fmt.Println(bobby) // prints: &{10 Bobby}
    fmt.Println(ralph) // prints: Ralph, age 12
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew

> Go-spew implements a deep pretty printer for Go data structures to aid in debugging.

Answer (score 2):

```
fmt.Printf("%v", whatever)
```

In Go is like print_r(), var_dump(), var_export() in PHP. (The `%v` is the important part.)

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

For debugging I use this:

```
func printVars(w io.Writer, writePre bool, vars ...interface{}) {
    if writePre {
        io.WriteString(w, "<pre>\n")
    }
    for i, v := range vars {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "» item %d type %T:\n", i, v)
        j, err := json.MarshalIndent(v, "", "    ")
        switch {
        case err != nil:
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "error: %v", err)
        case len(j) < 3: // {}, empty struct maybe or empty string, usually mean unexported struct fields
            w.Write([]byte(html.EscapeString(fmt.Sprintf("%+v", v))))
        default:
            w.Write(j)
        }
        w.Write([]byte("\n\n"))
    }
    if writePre {
        io.WriteString(w, "</pre>\n")
    }
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/Fc52vlzEF7)