# How do you ignore the String() method when printing a golang struct?

Tags: debugging, go

I have a golang struct, and have created a `String()` method for use in the program's normal operation. I now want to see the whole contents of the struct. I tried the usual `%+v` format but it seems to use the `String()` method instead of showing me all the fields. How can I output the raw structure data?

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/SxTVOtwVV-9

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    Jekyl string
    Hyde  string
}

func (foo Foo) String() string {
    return foo.Jekyl // how I want it to show in the rest of the program
}

func main() {
    bar := Foo{Jekyl: "good", Hyde: "evil"}
    fmt.Printf("%+v", bar) // debugging to see what's going on, can't see the evil side
}
```

Outputs

```
good
```

But I want to see what you get without the String() method implemented

```
{Jekyl:good Hyde:evil}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `%#v` format

```
fmt.Printf("%#v", bar)
```

Outputs:

```
main.Foo{Jekyl:"good", Hyde:"evil"}
```

ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/26116578/10245

https://play.golang.org/p/YWIf6zGU-En

Answer (score 3):

While your answer is correct, it's a common practice to use another type to strip off all methods of a struct and use other ones (this is used usually in marshalling/unmarshalling).

If a type is defined as `type stripped Foo` then the method `Foo.String()` will no longer be used.

Code: https://play.golang.org/p/Ba2VvLAm92a

Output: `{Jekyl:good Hyde:evil}`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to print full key value pair for any object is like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    Jekyl string
    Hyde  string
}

func main() {
    bar := Foo{Jekyl: "good", Hyde: "evil"}
    b, err := json.Marshal(bar)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error marshaling object")
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("bar data : ", string(b))
}
```

Output:

```
 bar data :  {"Jekyl":"good","Hyde":"evil"}
```

Go playground ref: https://play.golang.org/p/VJZNmpC_wNJ